# Javascript function changing the value of a variable as it passes between pages

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an in house web based HR system, so that our HR department can track and report on certain things.  Most of the pages involve searches driven off employee ID. They also have the option of clicking a link which opens a popup window where they can search for employee ID by employee's last name.  This is where the problem is.  On the popup page they click the desired employee ID and it submits it back to the search page.  I'm pretty sure this was working just fine during testing, but then I changed the SQL table behind the search to one that included the entire employee pool and I started finding weird results every now and then. After tested I figured out it's happen during the Javascript function that submits the ID back.  I don't understand why it's happening as the function is pretty simple, and I didn't change this code between testing and final. It only does it with some employees so it's possible it was always doing it and I just didn't happen test anyone it was doing it with.

```
function submitssn1(ssn) 
{
    window.opener.location.href="hr_main.php?empID=" + ssn; 
    window.close();
}
```

Below is the code used to initiate the function.

```
<td><a href="javascript:submitssn1(' . $row["PersonID"] . ')"><Font 
face=verdana size=2>' . $row["PersonID"] . '</font></a></td>';
```

When you search by last name it pulls up the correct employee ID.  When I echo the ID before the submit function it's correct as well.  What gets submitted to the other page is a different ID though.  You can manually copy and past the ID back to the other page and the search works fine.  I've run out of ideas to check and I can't find anything similar online.  Any thoughts or advice would be greatly appreciated.

*I'm aware the code is old.  Part of what I'm doing is updating it.  I'm just asking if anyone knows why I might be getting the weird functionality of the Javascript submitting a different number then it's parameter.  It's weird because it does it in some instances, but not all.

Comment: with `$row[...]` you are requesting a PHP value, but you're using JavaScript, you need to use `<?php $row[..] ?>`

Comment: @BillBonney Why are you declaring a local variable named ssn when you are passing a parameter to your function with the same name?

Comment: **When I echo the ID before the submit function** I don't see an `echo`?

Comment: Please don't use `<font>` anymore. It's been deprecated for the past 20 years.

Comment: @RyanWilson not sure it's not my code and I'm not particularly familiar with Javascript until I started this project.  I do more PHP.

Comment: @BillBonney try modifying the function submitssn1 and remove the line var ssn; That may solve your issue.

Comment: @RyanWilson thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it didn't change anything in the results.  It's just so weird because it happens with some employees and not others.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening a window just to send a GET request, try using ajax, or at least use a hidden frame. Ajax is a modern method that runs int he background and returns request results (errors, data, etc.). Opening a "send" window is unreliable because you don't know if the data has actually been sent before you automatically close it.

Try using divs instead of tables. There are even table-like divs you can work with. There are online tools that can convert a simple table into divs. Tables are meant for tabular data, not markup.

Your most glaring problem, as Ryan pointed out, is that you are re-declaring a parameter inside a function.

I applied a CSS class to replace the Font tags.

Bascically, you should learn about CSS, use it instead of font and table tags, learn ajax (it's easy with jQuery), and use a javascript debugger (they often come with browsers) to tell you the errors you made, like redeclaring variables.

Javascript:

```
function submitssn1(ssn) 
{
    //var ssn; //why redeclare the variable that is declared as a function parameter above?
    window.opener.location.href="hr_main.php?empID=" + ssn; 
    window.close();
}
```

CSS:

```
.empID {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<td class="empID">
    <a href="javascript:submitssn1(' . $row["PersonID"] . ')">
        ' . $row["PersonID"] . '</a>
</td>';
```

PHP:

```
echo $_GET['ssn'];
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear in my question.  I'm only concerned with why I'm getting weird results in my Javascript.  I'm well aware of how CSS works and that this code is outdated.  I'm transitioning this code which was written in the 90s to a more modern system.  I'm concerned with getting it working functionally then I will go through and modernize the code. AS far as using divs this is tabular data.  You search by last name and it generate a table of employees with last names in the search criteria.